# Generating Dynamic Route Params from a Tree-like JSON Structure with Recursive Function Logic

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently working on a project where I have a tree-like JSON structure representing a hierarchical product catalog. Each node in the tree can have multiple children, and I need to generate unique route parameters for each node when editing its details. To achieve this, I have defined an interface called `IProductNodeRouteParams` that represents the required route parameter object.

However, I'm encountering an issue with correctly generating the route parameters for each node in the tree. The problem lies within the `generateParamsForTreeView` method, which is intended to recursively generate the route parameter object. Unfortunately, it assigns duplicate IDs to the appropriate properties in the IProductNodeRouteParams object. For example, when there are four children under the "Unity Edition" node, all four of them end up with the same configuration ID: `configurationId: '6495ec9d3dd61d4dddc52da9'`.

I'm seeking assistance and insights on how to modify the logic in order to generate unique route parameters from the tree-like JSON structure. I want each node to have its own corresponding ID assigned to the relevant property in the IProductNodeRouteParams object.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

**Tree JSON:**

```
[{"_id":"6495e8e43dd61d4dddc52529","name":"RAD","type":"modality","order":1,"children":[{"_id":"6495e90c3dd61d4dddc5255b","name":"RADspeed","type":"family","children":[{"_id":"6495e91b3dd61d4dddc5259e","name":"Basic Radiography","children":[{"_id":"6495e93b3dd61d4dddc525f1","name":"Pro Style Edition","type":"product","children":[{"_id":"6495e9853dd61d4dddc52666","name":"Manual MF","type":"configuration","children":[]}]}],"type":"application"}]}]},{"_id":"6495e7953dd61d4dddc522ee","name":"Mobile","type":"modality","order":2,"children":[{"_id":"6495e7a23dd61d4dddc52320","name":"MobileDaRt","type":"family","children":[{"_id":"6495e7b93dd61d4dddc52363","name":"Mobile Digital","children":[{"_id":"6495e7c93dd61d4dddc523b6","name":"MobileDaRt","type":"product","children":[{"_id":"6495e8033dd61d4dddc5242b","name":"MX8k","type":"configuration","children":[]}]}],"type":"application"}]}]},{"_id":"6495ea5d3dd61d4dddc527fb","name":"IXR","type":"modality","order":3,"children":[{"_id":"6495ea763dd61d4dddc5282d","name":"Trinias","type":"family","children":[{"_id":"6495ea823dd61d4dddc52870","name":"Card/Angio","children":[{"_id":"6495ea983dd61d4dddc528c3","name":"Unity Edition","type":"product","children":[{"_id":"6495eaee3dd61d4dddc52938","name":"Interventional Radiography","type":"configuration","children":[]},{"_id":"6495eb363dd61d4dddc529af","name":"Cardiology","type":"configuration","children":[]},{"_id":"6495eb5f3dd61d4dddc52a26","name":"Vascular Surgery","type":"configuration","children":[]},{"_id":"6495ec9d3dd61d4dddc52da9","name":"TESTProduct4","type":"configuration","children":[]}]}],"type":"application"}]}]},{"_id":"6495e9cc3dd61d4dddc5268a","name":"R/F","type":"modality","order":4,"children":[{"_id":"6495e9dc3dd61d4dddc526bc","name":"FLUOROspeed","type":"family","children":[{"_id":"6495e9ed3dd61d4dddc526ff","name":"Conventional","children":[{"_id":"6495e9ff3dd61d4dddc52752","name":"FLUOROspeed","type":"product","children":[{"_id":"6495ea2c3dd61d4dddc527d7","name":"X1 Edition","type":"configuration","children":[]}]}],"type":"application"}]}]},{"_id":"6495beae45989383e07dd4af","name":"R/F Zone","type":"modality","order":5,"children":[{"_id":"6495beba45989383e07dd4e1","name":"Flexavision","type":"family","children":[{"_id":"6495bec945989383e07dd524","name":"Remote","children":[{"_id":"6495beda45989383e07dd577","name":"Flexavision","type":"product","children":[{"_id":"6495bf1745989383e07dd5ec","name":"F4","type":"configuration","children":[]}]}],"type":"application"}]}]}]
```

**Interfaces:**

```
export interface IProductNodeRouteParams {
    familyId: string;
    productId: string;
    modalityId: string;
    applicationId: string;
    configurationId: string;
}.

export type IProductNode =
    | 'family'
    | 'product'
    | 'modality'
    | 'application'
    | 'configuration';


export type IProductType = 'regional' | 'dealer' | 'ebg';
```

Pipe:

```
public transform(
        product: IProduct | IProductHierarchy,
        node: IProductNode,
        type: IProductType,
    ): string {
const _product = product as IProductHierarchy;
const routeParams = this.generateParamsForTreeView(_product);

const encryptedParams = encryption(JSON.stringify(routeParams));

return `/${type}-products/${node}/edit/${encryptedParams}`;

}


private generateParamsForTreeView(
        product: IProductHierarchy
    ): IProductNodeRouteParams {
        const params: IProductNodeRouteParams = Object.create(null);

        if (product.children && product.children.length > 0) {
            product.children.forEach((child) => {
                const childParams = this.generateParamsForTreeView(child);
                Object.assign(params, childParams);
            });
        }

        switch (product.type) {
            case 'configuration':
                params.configurationId = product._id;
                break;
            case 'application':
                params.applicationId = product._id;
                break;
            case 'product':
                params.productId = product._id;
                break;
            case 'family':
                params.familyId = product._id;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        params.modalityId = product._id;

        return params;
    }
```

Comment: `Object.assign(params, childParams)`  you are just overriding the first product object with the generated child object. If you are expecting an object with the same tree structure , then you should have `params.children` as an array of child params and so on. So each time you generate childParams you push the object to `params.children` array.